# Caching in GORM mongo?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm using GORM mongo of ver. `6.1.4.RELEASE` inside Grails apps as well as stand-alone.

If I try to use caching in GORM-standard way:

```
SomeDomain.findAllByName( 'some', [ cache:true ] )
```

then I still see the queries in mongodb server logs. I also found nothing about caching in the [ref-doc](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/index.html).

So, obviously the caching is NOT supported as of now. Is it planned to be implemented? Can I use some tricks to enable caching out-of-the-box?

Comment: Hi @injecteer, any luck with this matter?

Comment: not really, but I used `org.grails.plugins:cache` to enable caching on controller level